# Database design to store ordered user photos?

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example,

user has `[image1.jpg, image2.jpg ,image3.jpg]`

user could reorder them to `[image2.jpg, image1.jpg, image3.jpg]`, add to the end, delete from any position

I can think of 2 methods to store them:

1. just store as `Array` type in the database. when the user adds/deletes/reorders photos, overwrite the entire array in the database
2. store many photos rows with `position` column belongs to 1 user. on insert add to last position + 1. on delete, have to shift the positions after the deleted positions back - 1

What is the recommended design?

Comment: This is a design decision for you to make. Stack Overflow is here to solve specific programming problems, not make design choices for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most natural design in SQL would be a separate table:

```
create table userImages (
    userImageId serial,
    userId int references users(userId),
    image varchar(255),
    position int
);
```

As you have noticed, if you want positions to be gapless and ordered, then you need to update all the rows.

This has several features/advantages:

- You can put the logic into a trigger or stored procedure so it is inside the database.
- You can add additional information about the images, such as the date they were added or soft deletes.
- The database can prevent duplicate images.

The alternative would be to store these as an array within a row in `users`.  To maintain the ordering, you would basically need to do this in the application.  That is, read the array, do deletes, inserts, and reorders, and then save the row again.

This has several features/disadvantages, such as:

- The application has to be responsible for the column, instead of the database.
- There is no place to put additional information about images.

I am generally biased toward the first approach, but there are some situations where the second is quite reasonable.

Comment: Can you show an example of the trigger I would need for option 1? I am thinking BEFORE UPDATE would do the trick. Option 2 makes a lot of sense to me... but I am told it is a violation of 1NF.

Comment: @kayla . . . This question is about database design.  If you have a question about triggers, ask that as a *new* question.

Answer (score -1):

What I think is. if photo ordered by some attribute, (e.g. last edit time) you just select XXX order by attribute.
if photo ordered by user require, we have to use 'position' column.